# Uploading a resume in a pdf file and displaying in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I would like to know how to upload a resume in a pdf file in an asp.net page. I know how to upload a simple txt file and when the fields are separated by ",". Here's my code.

```
using System.IO;
        string uploadfile = Server.MapPath("~/uploads3/") + FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(uploadfile);
        if (File.Exists(uploadfile))
        { 
        string inputline = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(uploadfile))
            {
                while ((inputline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string tempstr = inputline;
                    string firstname = tempstr.Substring(0, tempstr.IndexOf(","));
                    tempstr = tempstr.Substring(tempstr.IndexOf(",") + 1);
                    string lastname = tempstr.Substring(0, tempstr.IndexOf(","));
                    tempstr = tempstr.Substring(tempstr.IndexOf(",") + 1);
(...)
```

Now, I have absolutely no idea how to do this on a pdf file containing a resume. How to do that? Please explain your answers, I'm just new to system.io. Thanks again.

Comment: It would be much easier to just accept the PDF stream as a file and ask your users to provide first name and surname. Usability does not degrade from doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to take a look at the open source iTextSharp library. It provides all the methods you will need for writing to a PDF. There are plenty of other PDF writing libraries that can do the same. As far as I know it isn't practical to do this using System.IO. You can still upload a CSV file, have the codebehind do the formatting and PDF creation, and then save it to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is not an easy to read format. You will need a library to extract the needed information.

The iTextSharp library can work, but you will need to walk though the tree structure of the document.

A (sometimes) simple alternative is to use the [.Net port](http://www.squarepdf.net/pdfbox-in-net/) of PDFBox, as instructed in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C). PDFBox converts the PDF to a pure text representation that may be easier to parse. The bad side on this approach is that the IKVM.Net library that PDFBox uses is huge, ~17MB.